# WPF binding problem with certain property names

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, binding

I've stumbled over the following problem. I've got a checkbox whose `IsChecked` property is bound to a CLR property in my `MainWindow` class. Here's the source code.

Code behind (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`):

```
namespace MenuItemBindingTest {
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private bool m_backedVariable = false;
    public bool IsPressAndHoldEnabled {
      get { return this.m_backedVariable; }
      set {
        this.m_backedVariable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsPressAndHoldEnabled");
        MessageBox.Show("Item changed: " + this.m_backedVariable);
      }
    }

    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.m_checkbox.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
      if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

XAML code (`MainWindow.xaml`):

```
<Window x:Class="MenuItemBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Binding Problem Test" Width="525" Height="350">
  <DockPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="m_checkbox" 
              IsChecked="{Binding IsPressAndHoldEnabled}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Content="Is Press and Hold enabled"/>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The problem now is that the set accessor for the property `IsPressAndHoldEnabled` **is never called** (ie. the message box never shows) when the user checks or unchecks the check box. It does, however, work when I rename the property to something else - like `IsPressAndHoldEnabled2`.

My question now is: Why can't I use `IsPressAndHoldEnabled` as name for my property? Does this have anything to do with the property `Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled` existing?

Comment: Can you see any error in VS output window?

Comment: No, there are none. I'll checked this for something like "property not found" which you get when you provide an non-existing property name. But there were no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  I don't have answers why,  but I have workarounds:

Seperating the `IsPressAndHoldEnabled` property out to a seperate ViewModel class worked, unless the class was derived from FrameworkElement.

Also, changing from a regular property to a Dependency Property in the same MainWindow class worked -- the DP changed callback fires.

Comment: Strange.  Binding does not usually require the source to be a DP -- it can be a normal object...

Comment: Well, I tried this and it didn't worked for me. Here's what I changed the property code into:

Comment: Forget the previous comments. Here's what I wanted to say: Ok - but when using a DP it's rather complicated to do anything useful in the change listener as the dependency property usually is a static variable.

Comment: DependencyProperty is static,  but the first parameter of the DependencyPropertyChangedCallback is your object -- you just cast the DependencyObject to your own type and then optionally call a private instance PropertyChanged method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified TwoWay as your binding mode?  Although I think `CheckBox.IsChecked` defaults to `TwoWay` binding mode...

I think you may have messed up your binding context, so that it is not finding the `IsPressAndHoldEnabled` property. Bindings in WPF fail **silently** -- a royal pain if you ask me.

Check that the check-box is really bound to that property, and that the binding context really is your MainWindodw class object.

Comment: It does default to two-way and has a default bool? -> bool type converter

Comment: If this was a problem, it wouldn't have worked after I __renamed__ the property.